# Nancy doesn't find system.xml

Tags: razor, nancy

I have a Nancy view with a using statement:

```
@using System.Xml
@{ //code
}
<!-- rest of page -->
```

System.Xml is referenced in my project.

When I try to run the app I get a Razor Compilation Error:

```
Error compiling template: Views/index.cshtml

Errors:
[CS0234] Line: 1 Column: 18 - The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (show)

 Details:
 @using System.Xml
```

Other namespaces, e.g. System.Web also fail in the same way, even though they are included in the project.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of not configuring razor.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine#configuring-razor

Comment: Configuring razor per the doc gets rid of the compile time error. Now I get a runtime error: Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml'   Ideas? Thank you!